# How to create basic posts/blog with nanoc and then have it in the feed?

Tags: blogs, feed, nanoc

I just started with nanoc. I am wondering if someone can explain me how I should create blog posts and how to add them in the feed?

I know how to create items, but how do I create posts in the blog folder? Also how to show the 5 most recent posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blog posts are just like other items, and it’s up to you to decide how you want them to be identified. Some people like using “kind: article” while other people prefer to stick them in a content/blog/ directory.

nanoc comes with a [Blogging](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/docs/api/3.3/Nanoc/Helpers/Blogging.html) helper. Take a look at the `#atom_feed` method, which can be used for generating an Atom feed. This method takes an `:articles` parameter containing a list of articles (by default, it will take the items with “kind: article”). This way, you can create a feed for a specific collection of items.